# serverless/cloud solution ( ideally AWS) for moving zip files from vendor FTP to AWS s3 on a monthly basis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp

We have a vendor that provides us data files ( 4/5 files ~10 GB each) on a monthly basis. They provide these files on their FTP site that we connect to using the username and password provided by them.
We download the zip files, unzip them, extract some relevant files, Gzip them and upload them to our s3 bucket and from there we push the data to Redshift.

Currently I have a python script that runs on an EC2 instance that does all this, but I am sure there's a better "serverless" solution out there ( Ideally in AWS environment) that can do this for me since this doesnt seem to be a very unique use case.

I am looking for recommendations / alternate solutions for processing these files.

Thank you.

Comment: How big are those files?

Comment: 4/5 files at ~10 GB each zipped.

Comment: 10GB files are too big for lambdas, unfortunately. Unless they can be chopped into chunks, lambda isn't a good option.

Comment: One option is to stream the file and parse it on the fly.  Entries within a Zip file are separate and can be pulled out individually and sequentially.  But then you've got to stream one part to S3 and it could get messy.  I'd use Lambda to kick off a temporary EC2, and script the running of it with user data on spin up.  Then shut it down when you're done.  Still serverless in that a server isn't running the entire time.

Comment: yeah, I am starting to think thats my best option. Just surprised there is no "of the shelf" option.